# Am using a same feature file for logging in as 2 users for add and approve. But while running it shows null pointer exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, pageobjects, cucumber-java

I have just started using Cucumber with selenium. Please ignore if there is any errors from my side.
    I have 2 scenarioes.
    1. Login as user A and add profile.
    2. Login as user B and approve profile

I have a same file for the two scenarios.
 Feature file is shown below,

```
@Login 
Scenario Outline: Login into application with valid credentials
Given enter '<Username>' and '<Password>'   
When clicking submit button
Then System should logged into application 
Examples:
|Username|Password    |
|aaaa    |aaa@123     |

@LoginApprover 
Scenario Outline: Login as Approver application with valid credentials
Given enter approver credentials '<AppUsername>' and '<AppPassword>'    
When clicking login button
Then Approver should be logged into application 
Examples:
|AppUsername|AppPassword |
|bbb        |bbb@123   |
```

My page object class

```
public class Login extends AllDetails {

public Login(WebDriver dr) {
    driver = dr;

}

private final  By USERNAME = By.cssSelector("#wwww");
private final  By PASSWORD = By.cssSelector("#eeee");
private final  By SIGNIN_BUTTON = By.cssSelector("#login");

private final By ALERTMSG = By.xpath("//*[@class='alert alert-danger']/p");
public void enterUsername(String userName) {
    waitUntilElementIsDisplayedOnScreen(USERNAME);
    sendKeys(USERNAME, userName);
}

public void enterPassword(String password) {
    waitUntilElementIsDisplayedOnScreen(PASSWORD);
    sendKeys(PASSWORD, password);
}

public void clickSignInButton() {
    click(SIGNIN_BUTTON);
}

public void alertmessageVerification(String msg) {

    try {
        String mesg = driver.findElement(ALERTMSG)
                .getAttribute("innerText");

        Assert.assertEquals("Following message prompted successfully", msg,
                message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(String.format(
                "Following Message is not prompted ", msg));
    }
}
```

My step definition class,

```
public class LoginDefn extends details{

@Given("^enter '(.*)' and '(.*)'$")
public void enter_username_and_password(String username, String password)
        throws Throwable {
    lp=getPageFactoryObject(Login.class);
    lp.enterUsername(username);
    lp.enterPassword(password);
}

@When("^clicking submit button$")
public void clicking_submit_button() throws Throwable {
    lp.clickSignInButton();     
}


@Then("^System should logged into application$")
public void system_should_logged_into_application() throws Throwable {

}

@Then("^System should not logged into application and prompt msg as(.*)$")
public void system_should_not_logged_into_application_and_prompt_msg_as_Invalid_username_and_password(String msg) throws Throwable {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    lp.alertmessageVerification(msg);       
    //lp.clearusernameandpassword();
}

@Given("^enter approver credentials '(.*)' and '(.*)'$")
public void enter_approver_credentials_and_(String appusername, String apppassword) throws Throwable {
    lp.enterUsername(appusername);
    lp.enterPassword(apppassword);
}

@When("^clicking login button$")
public void clicking_login_button() throws Throwable {
    lp.clickSignInButton();
}

@Then("^Approver should be logged into application$")
public void approver_should_be_logged_into_application() throws Throwable {
    //do nothing
}
```

}
My test runner class

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = { "src\\test\\java\\com\\Features\\" }, glue = 
{"definitions" }, plugin = {
"pretty", "json:target/cucumber.json" }, tags = 
{"@Login,@LoginApprover"}, monochrome = true)
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
```

Anyone please help me solve this issue.

Comment: If possible provide details and AllDetails java files.

Comment: @Akarsh.Thanks for your concern. The issue has been fixed. For the approver login I removed the tag Loginapprover. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see where you are defining the type of "lp" used in your steps class.  I see that you attempt to initialize it there, but it's never been declared that I can see.  You likely mean to define it as class Login (your page object).  If you intend to use it in every (or nearly every) step you should define it inside the steps class as:

```
public class LoginDefn extends details{

Login lp;

@Given("^enter '(.*)' and '(.*)'$")

public void enter_username_and_password(String username, String password)
        throws Throwable {
    lp=getPageFactoryObject(Login.class);
```

Then the rest of the code, I would think, would work without error, but I did not delve much deeper upon spotting that.

Comment: Actually I was adding a profile using another feature file, in that time after adding the profile I have to login as another user and approve it. The issue has been fixed by adding the approver login in the same feature file. Thanks for your suggestion.